# HTML/JavaScript disable elements

Tags: javascript, html

I have a dropdown navigation on my site

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Homepage</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
                
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button onclick="mainDropdown()" class="mainDropdown">Videos</button>
        <ul class="dropdownList" id="dropdownList">

            <button id="intro">Introduction</button>
            <button id="start">Getting Started</button>

        </ul>
    </div>
                    
    <li class="test"><a href="index.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

I have this in my html the UL around everything can be ignored as that isn't a part of the problem nor are the top two LIs

The problem I'm having is with the dropdown division.

```js
function mainDropdown() {
    var dropdown = document.getElementById("dropdownList");
    dropdown.classList.toggle("active");
    if(dropdown.classList.contains("active")) {
        document.getElementById("intro").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("start").style.display = "block";
    } else if(!dropdown.classList.contains("active")) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            document.getElementById("intro").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("start").style.display = "none";
        }, 300);
    }
}
```

This is the javascript method (vanilla, trying to not use JQuery in this project, just as a heads up).
This works fine - however, I'm looking for a better way to do this. because when I come to add more sections then the javascript method is going to get quite lengthy.

Is there a method I can use to get the children of the dropdownList UL so I can loop through them and set their display? Instead of adding a bunch of the same line.

Comment: It is part of the problem; the HTML is invalid. Once that happens, how CSS & JavaScript are going to react is undefined. A `ul` cannot have a `div` child nor a `button` child. You might be lucky and get some agreement among some of the browsers on what they'll do, but next month? Next year?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a method I can use to get the children of the dropdownList UL so I can loop through them and set their display?

You could get the list of items via [`querySelectorAll('#dropdownList > *')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

Or you could use a css selector to toggle the display:

```css
#dropdownList {
  display: none;
}

#dropdownList.active {
  display: block;
}
```

Or if you need to do individual items for some reason:

```css
#dropdownList > * {
  display: none;
}

#dropdownList.active > * {
  display: block;
}
```